# is there a published answer in this (Geotools MapStyle turtorial, select features)

Tags: feature-selection, geotools

Is there a published solution on Geotools userguide task?
In the link:
https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/map/style.html
there is a "Things to try":
In the Geometry and CRS tutorial we saw how to change the Coordinate Reference System of a MapContent. Try the following:

1. Modify this application so that you can change the CRS in which the
   features are displayed.
2. Display the bc_voting_areas shapefile and change the CRS to
   EPSG:4326
3. Now try to use the selection tool. You will find that it no longer
   works !

I would like to find objects from different layers, who has different CRS, regardless of the map-window's CRS

This is my code that misses features in some layers (I can't understund why):

```
void selectFeatures(MapMouseEvent ev) {
Point screenPos = ev.getPoint();
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(screenPos.x - 2, screenPos.y - 2, 5, 5);
AffineTransform screenToWorld = mapFrame.getMapPane().getScreenToWorldTransform();
Rectangle2D worldRect = screenToWorld.createTransformedShape(screenRect).getBounds2D();
ReferencedEnvelope bbox = new ReferencedEnvelope(worldRect,mapFrame.getMapContent().getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
try {
    Iterator<Layer> it = map.layers().iterator();
    IDs = new HashSet<>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Layer l = it.next();
        if (l.isSelected()) {
            selectedFeatures = grabFeaturesInBoundingBox(bbox, l.getFeatureSource());
            SimpleFeatureIterator iter = selectedFeatures.features();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = iter.next();
                IDs.add(feature.getIdentifier());
                System.out.println("   " + feature.getIdentifier());
            }
            iter.close();
        }
    }
    if (IDs.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("   no feature selected");
    } else {
        doSometing...
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}}

SimpleFeatureCollection grabFeaturesInBoundingBox(ReferencedEnvelope click, FeatureSource<?, ?> fs) throws Exception {
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = null;
FeatureType schema = fs.getSchema();
String geometryPropertyName = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
ReferencedEnvelope bbox = click.transform(targetCRS, true);
Filter filter = ff.bbox(ff.property(geometryPropertyName), bbox);
sfc = featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
return sfc;}
```

Comment: I don't think so, is there a specific issue you're having?

Comment: I would like to find objects intersecting the "pick box" from different layers (they have different CRS) regardless of the map windows CRS.

Comment: please [edit] your question so it is actually about your problem and add the code you have tried so far

Comment: I had forgotten to set the new featureSource (layer iterator) in grabFeaturesInBoundingBox(),  setFeatureSource((SimpleFeatureSource)fs);